# What the best way (or standard practice) to organize the cache in RESTfull api and reduce load on a server?

Tags: http, caching, cache-control

HTTP Cache.

Am I right if I say that HTTP Cache is for send or not send a content(body, not headers ;) ) to the clients? It helps to reduce the count of transferred data between server and clients, but not the load on the server. HTTP Cache doesn't even need to do this. This is not its problem. So HTTP Cache doesn't care about the server-side.

Hence the question. What the best way to reduce the load on the server. Simplify the thought - why should we generate a content for response if we are not going to send this content to the client. Why should we execute the heavy queries to the DB if gotten data won't be sent to client. Yes, we have to find out whether data for request was modified or not. Maybe somehow we could store this information? But if we are talking about highly dynamic data. For example, we have to cache the request which retrieve a bunch of photos and we could put the filters (by distance - around 1000m, by time - within 1h, by category, ... ) and sorting params (by distance - the nearest to a client, by time, ...) on the photos. And the same photo could land to the different responses with different params.

Comment: could you make your question more readable its too long

Answer (score 0):

We have the request: http://api.myproject/timeline?lat=41.00001&lon=35.80012&category=1&timelimit=60&distance=1000. We have to create a unique identifier for this request. We are creating this identifier based on GET params - **request_key**, for example. When we fetch data for response (execute DB queries, prepare data to response, etc...) we have to calculate a hash for gotten data - **data_key**. Now we have 2 keys - query identifier and data key. We store this 2 keys and objects id. It could/must be a fast storage: memcache or redis. After that we send a response to the client and put Etag with data_key in headers. When the client will do another request to fetch data, we will generate request key, try to find the value for this key in memcache. If we find the request key and the Etag (taken from hreader) matches data_key we understand that data was not changed for this request and just return 304 http code to the client. When an object is changed we have to delete all stored pairs request_key and data_key from memcache where this object occurred. For that reason we are storing objects id with the pair (request_key,  data_key).